# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated error

Tags: .net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    dbcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["modelConnectionString"].ToString());
    dbcon.Open();
    Session["connection"] = dbcon;
}

protected void create_account_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        String username = username_textbox.Text;
        String pass = pwd_textbox.Text;
        String mob = mobile_textbox.Text;
        String email = email_textbox.Text;
        String add = address_textbox.Text;
        String ques = question_drop_down.Text;
        String ans = answer_textbox.Text;

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into bankdb(username,password,email,mobile,address,secQue,secAns) values(@username,@password,@email,@mobile,@address,@question,@answer)", dbcon);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mob);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", add);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", ques);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", ans);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //update = 1;
        //Session["inserted"] = update.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("registerSucessfully.aspx");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at BankMgtNew.new_register.create_account_button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\dot net\projects\BankMgtNew\BankMgtNew\new_register.aspx.cs:line 42 ClientConnectionId:4d3fc507-a71a-49e1-83d6-49a93ab41096

Comment: The length of the value your are inserting into one of your columns is larger than the column can hold. post example data and your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

The values what you are passing may be greater than the size of data type what u have mentioned for the table columns , compare the value data size with column data type size.